# how to get my code to loop through each event id in the list while also looping through json in order to capture every fight?

Tags: python, web-scraping, error-handling

im pretty new to coding, learning some python and im trying to figure out how to scrape stats from espn ufc site. I can get it to print out seperate dictionaries for each event, but I cant figure out how to capture all fights in each event. Right now I'm only getting one with this: "main_card_fight[0]", if I try to iterate through another list of numbers, I keep getting errors. I'm sure theres a more efficient way to do this..?

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

event_id = ["600004800","600004801","600006285","600015251"]

for id in event_id:
    try:

        event = {'event': 0,
                 'fighter_1': 0,
                 'fighter_1_sig': 0,
                 'fighter_1_tot': 0,
                 'fighter_1_takedown': 0,
                 'fighter_1_control': 0,
                 'fighter_1_win': 0,
                 'fighter_2': 0,
                 'fighter_2_sig': 0,
                 'fighter_2_tot': 0,
                 'fighter_2_takedown': 0,
                 'fighter_2_control': 0,
                 'fighter_2_win': 0,
                 'result': 0,
                 }
        response = requests.get(
            f"https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/common/v3/sports/mma/ufc/fightcenter/{id}?region=us&lang=en&contentorigin=espn&showAirings=buy%2Clive%2Creplay&buyWindow=1m").text
        ufc_json = json.loads(response)
        event_name = ufc_json['event']['name']

        main_card_fight = ufc_json['cards']['main']['competitions']
        fighter_1_name = main_card_fight[0]['competitors'][0]['athlete']['displayName']
        fighter_1_sig = main_card_fight[0]['competitors'][0]['stats'][2]['displayValue']
        fighter_1_tot = main_card_fight[0]['competitors'][0]['stats'][1]['displayValue']
        fighter_1_takedown = main_card_fight[0]['competitors'][0]['stats'][7]['displayValue']
        fighter_1_control = main_card_fight[0]['competitors'][0]['stats'][6]['displayValue']
        fighter_1_win = main_card_fight[0]['competitors'][0]['winner']
        fighter_2_name = main_card_fight[0]['competitors'][1]['athlete']['displayName']
        fighter_2_sig = main_card_fight[0]['competitors'][1]['stats'][2]['displayValue']
        fighter_2_tot = main_card_fight[0]['competitors'][1]['stats'][1]['displayValue']
        fighter_2_takedown = main_card_fight[0]['competitors'][1]['stats'][7]['displayValue']
        fighter_2_control = main_card_fight[0]['competitors'][1]['stats'][6]['displayValue']
        fighter_2_win = main_card_fight[0]['competitors'][1]['winner']
        fight_result = main_card_fight[0]['status']['result']['displayName']
        event.update({'event': event_name,
                      'fighter_1': fighter_1_name,
                      'fighter_1_sig': fighter_1_sig,
                      'fighter_1_tot': fighter_1_tot,
                      'fighter_1_takedown': fighter_1_takedown,
                      'fighter_1_control': fighter_1_control,
                      'fighter_1_win': fighter_1_win,
                      'fighter_2': fighter_2_name,
                      'fighter_2_sig': fighter_2_sig,
                      'fighter_2_tot': fighter_2_tot,
                      'fighter_2_takedown': fighter_2_takedown,
                      'fighter_2_control': fighter_2_control,
                      'fighter_2_win': fighter_2_win,
                      'result': fight_result
                      })
        print(event)
    except KeyError:
        print("key error")
        continue
    except IndexError:
        print("index error")
        continue
```

Answer (score 1):

You are scraping an API returning a JSON response: why are you you transforming it to text, only to then parse it again as json?

The following example should get you started (based on your code):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

event_id = ["600004800","600004801","600006285","600015251"]

for id in event_id:
    try:
        r = requests.get(
            f"https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/common/v3/sports/mma/ufc/fightcenter/{id}?region=us&lang=en&contentorigin=espn&showAirings=buy%2Clive%2Creplay&buyWindow=1m")
        print(pd.json_normalize(r.json(), record_path=['cards', 'prelims1', 'competitions', 'competitors']))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

This prints in terminal (a huge dataframe):

```
id  uid type    order   winner  displayRecord   stats   athlete.id  athlete.uid athlete.firstName   athlete.lastName    athlete.displayName athlete.fullName    athlete.shortName   athlete.displayHeight   athlete.displayWeight   athlete.headshot.href   athlete.headshot.alt    athlete.flag.href   athlete.flag.alt    athlete.flag.rel    athlete.gender  athlete.displayReach    athlete.stance.id   athlete.stance.text athlete.weightClass.id  athlete.weightClass.text    athlete.weightClass.shortName   athlete.weightClass.slug    athlete.images  athlete.link.language   athlete.link.rel    athlete.link.href   athlete.link.text   athlete.link.shortText  athlete.link.isExternal athlete.link.isPremium  athlete.color   athlete.alternateColor
0   3091099 s:3301~a:3091099    athlete 2   True    23-4-0  [{'name': 'knockDowns', 'displayName': 'Knockdowns', 'shortDisplayName': 'Knockdowns', 'description': 'Knockdowns', 'abbreviation': 'KD', 'value': 0.0, 'displayValue': '0'}, {'name': 'totalStrikes', 'displayName': 'totalStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'totalStrikes', 'description': 'totalStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'totalStrikes', 'value': 19, 'displayValue': '19/26'}, {'name': 'sigStrikes', 'displayName': 'sigStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'sigStrikes', 'description': 'sigStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'sigStrikes', 'value': 7, 'displayValue': '7/12'}, {'name': 'headStrikes', 'displayName': 'headStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'headStrikes', 'description': 'headStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'headStrikes', 'value': 3, 'displayValue': '3/8'}, {'name': 'bodyStrikes', 'displayName': 'bodyStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'bodyStrikes', 'description': 'bodyStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'bodyStrikes', 'value': 2, 'displayValue': '2/2'}, {'name': 'legStrikes', 'displayName': 'legStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'legStrikes', 'description': 'legStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'legStrikes', 'value': 2, 'displayValue': '2/2'}, {'name': 'timeInControl', 'displayName': 'Time in Control', 'description': 'Time in Control', 'abbreviation': 'TIC', 'value': 70.0, 'displayValue': '1:10'}, {'name': 'takedowns', 'displayName': 'takedowns', 'shortDisplayName': 'takedowns', 'description': 'takedowns', 'abbreviation': 'takedowns', 'value': 2, 'displayValue': '2/3'}, {'name': 'submissions', 'displayName': 'Submissions', 'shortDisplayName': 'Submissions', 'description': 'Submissions', 'abbreviation': 'SM', 'value': 1.0, 'displayValue': '1'}]    3091099 s:3301~a:3091099    Andre   Muniz   Andre Muniz Andre Muniz A. Muniz    6' 1"   185 lbs https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/full/3091099.png  Andre Muniz https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/countries/500/bra.png Brazil  [country-flag]  MALE    78" 76  Southpaw    972 Middleweight    Middleweight    middleweight    [{'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/stance/left/3091099.png', 'rel': ['leftStance']}, {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/stance/right/3091099.png', 'rel': ['rightStance']}]  en-US   [playercard, desktop, athlete]  http://www.espn.com/mma/fighter/_/id/3091099/andre-muniz    Player Card Player Card False   False   #FFDF00 #002776
1   2431314 s:3301~a:2431314    athlete 1   False   26-10-0 [{'name': 'knockDowns', 'displayName': 'Knockdowns', 'shortDisplayName': 'Knockdowns', 'description': 'Knockdowns', 'abbreviation': 'KD', 'value': 0.0, 'displayValue': '0'}, {'name': 'totalStrikes', 'displayName': 'totalStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'totalStrikes', 'description': 'totalStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'totalStrikes', 'value': 15, 'displayValue': '15/23'}, {'name': 'sigStrikes', 'displayName': 'sigStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'sigStrikes', 'description': 'sigStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'sigStrikes', 'value': 11, 'displayValue': '11/19'}, {'name': 'headStrikes', 'displayName': 'headStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'headStrikes', 'description': 'headStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'headStrikes', 'value': 5, 'displayValue': '5/13'}, {'name': 'bodyStrikes', 'displayName': 'bodyStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'bodyStrikes', 'description': 'bodyStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'bodyStrikes', 'value': 4, 'displayValue': '4/4'}, {'name': 'legStrikes', 'displayName': 'legStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'legStrikes', 'description': 'legStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'legStrikes', 'value': 2, 'displayValue': '2/2'}, {'name': 'timeInControl', 'displayName': 'Time in Control', 'description': 'Time in Control', 'abbreviation': 'TIC', 'value': 53.0, 'displayValue': '0:53'}, {'name': 'takedowns', 'displayName': 'takedowns', 'shortDisplayName': 'takedowns', 'description': 'takedowns', 'abbreviation': 'takedowns', 'value': 1, 'displayValue': '1/2'}, {'name': 'submissions', 'displayName': 'Submissions', 'shortDisplayName': 'Submissions', 'description': 'Submissions', 'abbreviation': 'SM', 'value': 0.0, 'displayValue': '0'}] 2431314 s:3301~a:2431314    Jacare  Souza   Jacare Souza    Jacare Souza    J. Souza    6' 1"   186 lbs https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/full/2431314.png  Jacare Souza    https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/countries/500/bra.png Brazil  [country-flag]  MALE    72" 75  Orthodox    972 Middleweight    Middleweight    middleweight    [{'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/stance/left/2431314.png', 'rel': ['leftStance']}, {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/stance/right/2431314.png', 'rel': ['rightStance']}]  en-US   [playercard, desktop, athlete]  http://www.espn.com/mma/fighter/_/id/2431314/jacare-souza   Player Card Player Card False   False   #FFDF00 #002776
2   3734391 s:3301~a:3734391    athlete 2   False   12-4-0  [{'name': 'knockDowns', 'displayName': 'Knockdowns', 'shortDisplayName': 'Knockdowns', 'description': 'Knockdowns', 'abbreviation': 'KD', 'value': 0.0, 'displayValue': '0'}, {'name': 'totalStrikes', 'displayName': 'totalStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'totalStrikes', 'description': 'totalStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'totalStrikes', 'value': 34, 'displayValue': '34/65'}, {'name': 'sigStrikes', 'displayName': 'sigStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'sigStrikes', 'description': 'sigStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'sigStrikes', 'value': 32, 'displayValue': '32/63'}, {'name': 'headStrikes', 'displayName': 'headStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'headStrikes', 'description': 'headStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'headStrikes', 'value': 19, 'displayValue': '19/44'}, {'name': 'bodyStrikes', 'displayName': 'bodyStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'bodyStrikes', 'description': 'bodyStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'bodyStrikes', 'value': 13, 'displayValue': '13/19'}, {'name': 'legStrikes', 'displayName': 'legStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'legStrikes', 'description': 'legStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'legStrikes', 'value': 0, 'displayValue': '0/0'}, {'name': 'timeInControl', 'displayName': 'Time in Control', 'description': 'Time in Control', 'abbreviation': 'TIC', 'value': 157.0, 'displayValue': '2:37'}, {'name': 'takedowns', 'displayName': 'takedowns', 'shortDisplayName': 'takedowns', 'description': 'takedowns', 'abbreviation': 'takedowns', 'value': 3, 'displayValue': '3/20'}, {'name': 'submissions', 'displayName': 'Submissions', 'shortDisplayName': 'Submissions', 'description': 'Submissions', 'abbreviation': 'SM', 'value': 0.0, 'displayValue': '0'}]  3734391 s:3301~a:3734391    Mike    Grundy  Mike Grundy Mike Grundy M. Grundy   5' 7"   145 lbs https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/full/3734391.png  Mike Grundy https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/countries/500/eng.png England [country-flag]  MALE    72" 75  Orthodox    999 Featherweight   Featherweight   featherweight   [{'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/stance/left/3734391.png', 'rel': ['leftStance']}, {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/stance/right/3734391.png', 'rel': ['rightStance']}]  en-US   [playercard, desktop, athlete]  http://www.espn.com/mma/fighter/_/id/3734391/mike-grundy    Player Card Player Card False   False   #CE1124 #001CC3
3   3949555 s:3301~a:3949555    athlete 1   True    12-6-2  [{'name': 'knockDowns', 'displayName': 'Knockdowns', 'shortDisplayName': 'Knockdowns', 'description': 'Knockdowns', 'abbreviation': 'KD', 'value': 0.0, 'displayValue': '0'}, {'name': 'totalStrikes', 'displayName': 'totalStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'totalStrikes', 'description': 'totalStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'totalStrikes', 'value': 83, 'displayValue': '83/173'}, {'name': 'sigStrikes', 'displayName': 'sigStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'sigStrikes', 'description': 'sigStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'sigStrikes', 'value': 80, 'displayValue': '80/168'}, {'name': 'headStrikes', 'displayName': 'headStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'headStrikes', 'description': 'headStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'headStrikes', 'value': 40, 'displayValue': '40/118'}, {'name': 'bodyStrikes', 'displayName': 'bodyStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'bodyStrikes', 'description': 'bodyStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'bodyStrikes', 'value': 27, 'displayValue': '27/36'}, {'name': 'legStrikes', 'displayName': 'legStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'legStrikes', 'description': 'legStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'legStrikes', 'value': 13, 'displayValue': '13/14'}, {'name': 'timeInControl', 'displayName': 'Time in Control', 'description': 'Time in Control', 'abbreviation': 'TIC', 'value': 23.0, 'displayValue': '0:23'}, {'name': 'takedowns', 'displayName': 'takedowns', 'shortDisplayName': 'takedowns', 'description': 'takedowns', 'abbreviation': 'takedowns', 'value': 1, 'displayValue': '1/1'}, {'name': 'submissions', 'displayName': 'Submissions', 'shortDisplayName': 'Submissions', 'description': 'Submissions', 'abbreviation': 'SM', 'value': 0.0, 'displayValue': '0'}]  3949555 s:3301~a:3949555    Lando   Vannata Lando Vannata   Lando Vannata   L. Vannata  5' 9"   146 lbs https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/full/3949555.png  Lando Vannata   https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/countries/500/usa.png USA [country-flag]  MALE    71" 75  Orthodox    986 Lightweight Lightweight lightweight [{'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/stance/left/3949555.png', 'rel': ['leftStance']}, {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/stance/right/3949555.png', 'rel': ['rightStance']}]  en-US   [playercard, desktop, athlete]  http://www.espn.com/mma/fighter/_/id/3949555/lando-vannata  Player Card Player Card False   False   #3C3B6E #B22234
4   4237148 s:3301~a:4237148    athlete 2   False   13-8-0  [{'name': 'knockDowns', 'displayName': 'Knockdowns', 'shortDisplayName': 'Knockdowns', 'description': 'Knockdowns', 'abbreviation': 'KD', 'value': 0.0, 'displayValue': '0'}, {'name': 'totalStrikes', 'displayName': 'totalStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'totalStrikes', 'description': 'totalStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'totalStrikes', 'value': 4, 'displayValue': '4/5'}, {'name': 'sigStrikes', 'displayName': 'sigStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'sigStrikes', 'description': 'sigStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'sigStrikes', 'value': 4, 'displayValue': '4/5'}, {'name': 'headStrikes', 'displayName': 'headStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'headStrikes', 'description': 'headStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'headStrikes', 'value': 2, 'displayValue': '2/3'}, {'name': 'bodyStrikes', 'displayName': 'bodyStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'bodyStrikes', 'description': 'bodyStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'bodyStrikes', 'value': 1, 'displayValue': '1/1'}, {'name': 'legStrikes', 'displayName': 'legStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'legStrikes', 'description': 'legStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'legStrikes', 'value': 1, 'displayValue': '1/1'}, {'name': 'timeInControl', 'displayName': 'Time in Control', 'description': 'Time in Control', 'abbreviation': 'TIC', 'value': 12.0, 'displayValue': '0:12'}, {'name': 'takedowns', 'displayName': 'takedowns', 'shortDisplayName': 'takedowns', 'description': 'takedowns', 'abbreviation': 'takedowns', 'value': 0, 'displayValue': '0/0'}, {'name': 'submissions', 'displayName': 'Submissions', 'shortDisplayName': 'Submissions', 'description': 'Submissions', 'abbreviation': 'SM', 'value': 0.0, 'displayValue': '0'}]    4237148 s:3301~a:4237148    Jamie   Pickett Jamie Pickett   Jamie Pickett   J. Pickett  6' 2"   185 lbs https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/full/4237148.png  Jamie Pickett   https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/countries/500/usa.png USA [country-flag]  MALE    80" 75  Orthodox    972 Middleweight    Middleweight    middleweight    [{'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/stance/left/4237148.png', 'rel': ['leftStance']}, {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/stance/right/4237148.png', 'rel': ['rightStance']}]  en-US   [playercard, desktop, athlete]  http://www.espn.com/mma/fighter/_/id/4237148/jamie-pickett  Player Card Player Card False   False   #3C3B6E #B22234
5   4339150 s:3301~a:4339150    athlete 1   True    12-3-0  [{'name': 'knockDowns', 'displayName': 'Knockdowns', 'shortDisplayName': 'Knockdowns', 'description': 'Knockdowns', 'abbreviation': 'KD', 'value': 1.0, 'displayValue': '1'}, {'name': 'totalStrikes', 'displayName': 'totalStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'totalStrikes', 'description': 'totalStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'totalStrikes', 'value': 33, 'displayValue': '33/40'}, {'name': 'sigStrikes', 'displayName': 'sigStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'sigStrikes', 'description': 'sigStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'sigStrikes', 'value': 26, 'displayValue': '26/32'}, {'name': 'headStrikes', 'displayName': 'headStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'headStrikes', 'description': 'headStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'headStrikes', 'value': 21, 'displayValue': '21/27'}, {'name': 'bodyStrikes', 'displayName': 'bodyStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'bodyStrikes', 'description': 'bodyStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'bodyStrikes', 'value': 5, 'displayValue': '5/5'}, {'name': 'legStrikes', 'displayName': 'legStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'legStrikes', 'description': 'legStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'legStrikes', 'value': 0, 'displayValue': '0/0'}, {'name': 'timeInControl', 'displayName': 'Time in Control', 'description': 'Time in Control', 'abbreviation': 'TIC', 'value': 11.0, 'displayValue': '0:11'}, {'name': 'takedowns', 'displayName': 'takedowns', 'shortDisplayName': 'takedowns', 'description': 'takedowns', 'abbreviation': 'takedowns', 'value': 0, 'displayValue': '0/0'}, {'name': 'submissions', 'displayName': 'Submissions', 'shortDisplayName': 'Submissions', 'description': 'Submissions', 'abbreviation': 'SM', 'value': 0.0, 'displayValue': '0'}]   4339150 s:3301~a:4339150    Jordan  Wright  Jordan Wright   Jordan Wright   J. Wright   6' 2"   190 lbs https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/full/4339150.png  Jordan Wright   https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/countries/500/usa.png USA [country-flag]  MALE    77" 75  Orthodox    972 Middleweight    Middleweight    middleweight    [{'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/stance/left/4339150.png', 'rel': ['leftStance']}, {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/stance/right/4339150.png', 'rel': ['rightStance']}]  en-US   [playercard, desktop, athlete]  http://www.espn.com/mma/fighter/_/id/4339150/jordan-wright  Player Card Player Card False   False   #3C3B6E #B22234
6   4339152 s:3301~a:4339152    athlete 2   False   10-4-0  [{'name': 'knockDowns', 'displayName': 'Knockdowns', 'shortDisplayName': 'Knockdowns', 'description': 'Knockdowns', 'abbreviation': 'KD', 'value': 0.0, 'displayValue': '0'}, {'name': 'totalStrikes', 'displayName': 'totalStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'totalStrikes', 'description': 'totalStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'totalStrikes', 'value': 36, 'displayValue': '36/54'}, {'name': 'sigStrikes', 'displayName': 'sigStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'sigStrikes', 'description': 'sigStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'sigStrikes', 'value': 23, 'displayValue': '23/41'}, {'name': 'headStrikes', 'displayName': 'headStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'headStrikes', 'description': 'headStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'headStrikes', 'value': 13, 'displayValue': '13/30'}, {'name': 'bodyStrikes', 'displayName': 'bodyStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'bodyStrikes', 'description': 'bodyStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'bodyStrikes', 'value': 8, 'displayValue': '8/9'}, {'name': 'legStrikes', 'displayName': 'legStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'legStrikes', 'description': 'legStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'legStrikes', 'value': 2, 'displayValue': '2/2'}, {'name': 'timeInControl', 'displayName': 'Time in Control', 'description': 'Time in Control', 'abbreviation': 'TIC', 'value': 238.0, 'displayValue': '3:58'}, {'name': 'takedowns', 'displayName': 'takedowns', 'shortDisplayName': 'takedowns', 'description': 'takedowns', 'abbreviation': 'takedowns', 'value': 0, 'displayValue': '0/0'}, {'name': 'submissions', 'displayName': 'Submissions', 'shortDisplayName': 'Submissions', 'description': 'Submissions', 'abbreviation': 'SM', 'value': 0.0, 'displayValue': '0'}]  4339152 s:3301~a:4339152    Antonina    Shevchenko  Antonina Shevchenko Antonina Shevchenko A. Shevchenko   5' 8"   125 lbs https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/full/4339152.png  Antonina Shevchenko https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/countries/500/kgz.png Kyrgyzstan  [country-flag]  FEMALE  67" 76  Southpaw    1007    Women's Flyweight   W Flyweight womens-flyweight    [{'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/stance/left/4339152.png', 'rel': ['leftStance']}, {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/stance/right/4339152.png', 'rel': ['rightStance']}]  en-US   [playercard, desktop, athlete]  http://www.espn.com/mma/fighter/_/id/4339152/antonina-shevchenko    Player Card Player Card False   False   #E8112D #FFE704
7   3153106 s:3301~a:3153106    athlete 1   True    13-6-0  [{'name': 'knockDowns', 'displayName': 'Knockdowns', 'shortDisplayName': 'Knockdowns', 'description': 'Knockdowns', 'abbreviation': 'KD', 'value': 0.0, 'displayValue': '0'}, {'name': 'totalStrikes', 'displayName': 'totalStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'totalStrikes', 'description': 'totalStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'totalStrikes', 'value': 88, 'displayValue': '88/108'}, {'name': 'sigStrikes', 'displayName': 'sigStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'sigStrikes', 'description': 'sigStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'sigStrikes', 'value': 45, 'displayValue': '45/62'}, {'name': 'headStrikes', 'displayName': 'headStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'headStrikes', 'description': 'headStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'headStrikes', 'value': 32, 'displayValue': '32/43'}, {'name': 'bodyStrikes', 'displayName': 'bodyStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'bodyStrikes', 'description': 'bodyStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'bodyStrikes', 'value': 11, 'displayValue': '11/15'}, {'name': 'legStrikes', 'displayName': 'legStrikes', 'shortDisplayName': 'legStrikes', 'description': 'legStrikes', 'abbreviation': 'legStrikes', 'value': 2, 'displayValue': '2/4'}, {'name': 'timeInControl', 'displayName': 'Time in Control', 'description': 'Time in Control', 'abbreviation': 'TIC', 'value': 131.0, 'displayValue': '2:11'}, {'name': 'takedowns', 'displayName': 'takedowns', 'shortDisplayName': 'takedowns', 'description': 'takedowns', 'abbreviation': 'takedowns', 'value': 3, 'displayValue': '3/3'}, {'name': 'submissions', 'displayName': 'Submissions', 'shortDisplayName': 'Submissions', 'description': 'Submissions', 'abbreviation': 'SM', 'value': 3.0, 'displayValue': '3'}]  3153106 s:3301~a:3153106    Andrea  Lee Andrea Lee  Andrea Lee  A. Lee  5' 6"   125 lbs https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/full/3153106.png  Andrea Lee  https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/countries/500/usa.png USA [country-flag]  FEMALE  69.5"   75  Orthodox    1007    Women's Flyweight   W Flyweight womens-flyweight    [{'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/stance/left/3153106.png', 'rel': ['leftStance']}, {'href': 'https://a.espncdn.com/i/headshots/mma/players/stance/right/3153106.png', 'rel': ['rightStance']}]  en-US   [playercard, desktop, athlete]  http://www.espn.com/mma/fighter/_/id/3153106/andrea-lee Player Card Player Card False   False   #3C3B6E #B22234
```

You can further inspect, slice and dice that json response you receive, using pandas `json_normalize()`

Relevant documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html?highlight=json_normalize#

And for Requests: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/